# Do monsters despawn in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, I was playing a survival game on easy.at night, there were hostile mobs, but, when the sun had fully rose, all of the monsters were gone, even the spiders, creepers and endermen.
this also happened in a creative game.
     I would really like an answer, please leave one if you get the chance. 
Thanks!

Comment: When a chunk is unloaded, so are the mobs (and all other items) on it, although passive mobs won't be removed. So if you walked a distance away (far enough to unload the chunk) then all hostile mobs will despawn.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the mobs spawn only under a [certain light level](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Light#Effects_of_light), and burn up when exposed to the sun.

However, creepers don't. Something else must have had happened to them.